# What is wrong with my code? (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, area

So I am trying to learn how to code in Obj-C as of right now and my current goal is to write a simple command line program to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle; however, Xcode keeps throwing up errors at me when I try the program. 
Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Rectangle : NSObject {
@private
    int width;
    int height;
}

-(void) setWidth: (int) w;
-(void) setHeight: (int) h;
-(int)  width;
-(int)  height;
-(int)  area;
-(int)  perimeter;
@end

@implementation Rectangle

-(void) setWidth:(int)w
{
    width = w;
}
-(void) setHeight:(int)h
{
    height = h;
}
-(int) width
{
    return width;
}
-(int) height
{
    return height;
}
-(int) area
```

**It is at this line that i receive the error " Thread 1: stopped at breakpoint 1"**

```
{
    return height*width;
}
-(int) perimeter
{
    return 2 * width + 2 * height;
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv []){
    @autoreleasepool {
        Rectangle * shape1 = [Rectangle new];

        [shape1 setHeight: 5];
        [shape1 setWidth: 15];

        NSLog(@"the area of the rectangle is %i and the perimeter is %i", [shape1 area],    [shape1 perimeter]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should copy the entire error message you're getting from the compiler/gdb and paste it here.

Comment: I got this issue a few times where xcode was breaking at some "ghost" breakpoints that I couldn't see in the code editor, but if you hit cmd+alt+B and look at the breakpoints window you can disable or delete them from there.

Comment: It's not a breakpoint. Your program crashed. Have a look at the debugger window to get the error message and paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

the code is correct , in xcode u have a little arrow and pose button on the butom left click that or click on the top right where it is written brake point and press play

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct. It works for me.

Comment: Huh I just restarted my computer and now it works.. weird. Well thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There was a break point button for run button that was clicked on. sometimes this make u think code bad but it just stops at multiple places in the code